# Why did Madara pose as Tobi when with Deidara?

Tags: naruto

I'm confused about when we first meet Tobi. He becomes Deidara's partner and acts helpless. If he was Madara all along, why did he have to go through the process of getting accepted into the Akatsuki?

Examples: when capturing the 3 tails and when fighting Sasuke

Answer (score 4):

First of all

> Tobi is **not** Madara. He claims to be Madara, and everybody believes it, that's all.

Tobi's true identity is:

> Obito Uchiha. He pretends to be Madara because he does not want to reveal his true identity because he should already be dead.

He keeps his goofball attitude so

> that he can pretend to be someone else (Tobi),  but once everyone calls him Madara, he changes his attitude to serious.

Comment: So who did all the Akatsuki members think was the leader? When tobi was introduced for the first time, it was like he was a long time friend of Deidara who was trying to get into the Akatsuki

Comment: When Tobi (Obito) created the Akatsuki, he wanted everyone to think he was just another guy, so he made Pain the leader. Btw, it was also Nagato's dream to create the Akatsuki.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Tobi was able to pull that comic relief attitude, because he was encapsulated by spiral zetsu, who liked toilet humor.

Comment: Not so sure about that... :)